# PHP does not echo text before + and - sign

Tags: php, echo, arithmetic-expressions

With the following code:

```
    $a=1;
    $b=1;
    echo $a."%".$b." maradéka: "." = ".$a % $b."<br>";
    echo $a."+".$b." összege: "." = ".$a + $b."<br>";
```

I get this output:

```
    1%1 maradéka: = 0
    2
```

As you can see, the + syntax is the same as the % but it doesn't echo the text before the operation. Maybe I'm too tired or i don't know, but i can't figure it out :D
I've built dynamic web pages so far, but this one got me.

Comment: This is actually quite interesting find

Comment: It works because the string `1+1 összege: = 1` is typecast to an int `1` and then `1+1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is taking the numeric value of the first part and adding it to the second part. You'll want to group your math using parenthesis.

```
$a=1;
$b=1;
echo $a."%".$b." maradéka: "." = ".$a % $b."<br>";
echo $a."+".$b." összege: "." = ".($a + $b)."<br>";
```

Comment: To be clear, without the parentheses is the same as `echo (($a."+"....$a) + $b)."<br>";`, where the left hand side of the addition is a string beginning with `1`, and the right hand side is `int(1)`, hence the `2`.

Comment: +1 This is actually quite interesting how it processes the output. At first i did not realize that it could actually take the first value and add it to second value